# I'm a little confused

Tags: word, wordplay

I am trying to find a word that is 5 letters in length.

- Change the first letter to two other letters, and it comes to taunt
  you. (This becomes a 6-letter word.)
- Change the second letter to another letter, and it becomes all the
  rage.
- Change the third letter to another, and its importance changes.
- Change the last letter, and it becomes your gut feeling.

I am told that changing the fourth letter yields no English word (though I am sure someone on PE will find one).

What word am I looking for?

Comment: When you change the second letter and third, etc. do you leave the first letter as it is after the first change or do you use the original word?

Comment: Seems like non-connected modifiers, based on the comment about the 4th letter

Comment: Correct - each change is based off the original word.

Comment: changing the first letter to two other letters - is that to mean the resulting word for this case is 6 letters? or are there two different first letter swaps that can have similar outcome?

Comment: The first word is actually a 6 letter word after the conversion.  All others are 5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm thinking

> VAGUE

Change the first letter to two other letters, and it comes to taunt you.

> **BL**AGUE *or* **PL**AGUE

Change the second letter to another letter, and it becomes all the rage.

> V**O**GUE

Change the third letter to another, and it's importance changes.

> VA**L**UE

Change the last letter, and it becomes your gut feeling

> VAGU**S**

And

> It's easy to understand why you couldn't think of this one. It's, uh, a little hard to, uh, hmm.

Comment: OK, you always solve my questions way too quickly.  However, you are incorrect with the first clue, with one of the two letters.

Comment: Plague?  Though I don't suppose it would taunt you.

Comment: After looking up question_asker's first answer, I agree that it does fit, despite the fact that I was looking for Khale_Kitha's solution. (look up the second definition of the word).

Comment: Oh - right.  I wasn't thinking of it, that way.  Sleepiness Plagues me.

Comment: @APrough I added the other - I'll be honest, I didn't know the first one I chose before this puzzle.